# while(*s++ = *t++) ; in C

Tags: c

In C Programming Language by K&R, I keep on seeing codes like
`while(*s++ = *t++) ;` which is just one example from Chapter 5, Pointers. This is completely confusing for me because I though while loop was as follows:

```
while (something is true)
    do what your assigned to do
```

Is some kind of special case with C or have I missed something? Being a beginner C programmer, this just went over my head. Any explanation as to how `while(*s++ = *t++) ;` works would be great.

I'm not confused as to what the expression `(*s++ = *t++)` is stating. I'm just wondering why there is nothing in the body of the while loop.

Comment: In what context is the code? Is it an example of how to iterate over a string? If it is from a textbook then maybe they are teaching you how before you do stuff with it?

Comment: `I'm just wondering why there is nothing in the body of the while loop.` Because that code is just there to copy a string to other in compact way/few lines.

Comment: There is no other work to be done. The conditional is a statement too, it can have side effects. The only thing that is required, is that it needs to evaluate to a `bool`.

Comment: You shouldn't read K&R unless you are skilled at software archaeology. It follows an outdated version of the C standard which has since then been revised in 1995, 1999 and 2011. Apart from that, it's just page after page of preaching dangerous practice, sprinkled with many [errors](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html).

Comment: I don't think you will find a better book for learning C than K&R. C is an old language and it's not bad to learn a bit of history. Besides, you see code like in the question in every project. You can't say you know C if you don't know the "bad practices".

Answer (score 8):

You can think of the code like this, if broken to down the simplest commands:

```
while (1) {
    char c = *t;
    *s = c;
    s++;
    t++;
    if (!c) {
        break;
    }
}
```

To explain why it works, you assign `*t` to `*s` and then evaluate the result (`a=b` evaluates to the value being assigned). If it's non-zero, it continues. If it's zero, it ends the loop.

Comment: maybe change `!c` to `c == \0` ? I think part of the confusing is how the loop is broken out of

Comment: I wanted to keep the original expression there, but yes, that would make the original code clearer.

Comment: may be swap `t` and `s` i.e. copies from `t` to `s` ?

Comment: Right, I just assumed s=source, t=target and wrote the code without double-checking the original.

Answer (score 4):

`s` and `t` are most likely `char *` which mean they are null terminated. So once you iterate through them, they will return 0. 0 is false in C

Comment: It's most probably not `==`.

Comment: You mean it should be `==` instead of `=`? That's incorrect, it's supposed to be assignment.

Comment: yup, changed it, didn't see the `;` at the end

Answer (score 4):

There are several things going on here:

- An assignment statement, `x = y`, is actually an *expression* (equal to the just-assigned value), which can itself be used as part of more complex expression.  This is useful for multiple assignments (`x = y = z`), and loop conditions like `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)`.
- Unlike, say, Pascal or Java, C isn't strict about Boolean values.  Any nonzero value is true (i.e., causes the body of an `if`, `while`, or `for` statement to be executed), and zero (whether `0`, `0.0`, `'\0'`, or `NULL`) is false.
- Strings are represented as an array of characters (or a pointer to such an array) terminated by a NUL (zero) character.  So, if `p` is a pointer to a string, `*p == 0` means it's at the end of the string.
- A *postfix* `++` operator increments its variable, but returns the old value.
- A `while` loop may have an empty body.

Putting it all together, `while(*s++ = *t++);` is a valid C statement.

Moving the increments into the loop body gives the equivalent statement:

```
while (*s = *t)
{
   s++;
   t++;
}
```

And moving the assignment into the loop body gives:

```
while (1)
{
   if (!(*s = *t))
   {
      break;
   }

   s++;
   t++;
}
```

Or, equivalently,

```
while (1)
{
   // Copy one char from string t to string s.
   *s = *t;

   // If it was the string terminator, exit the loop. 
   if (*s == '\0')
   {
      break;
   }

   // Move both pointers to the next character.
   s++;
   t++;
}
```

The original expression `while(*s++ = *t++);` is just a code-golfed version of the above.

Comment: Superb step by step explanation!!

Answer (score 1):

In C, every string is terminated by `'\0'` character whose ASCII Code is `0`.

Hence when all the string in `t` is copied to `s`. The loop will terminate because last character copied was `0` which is `false` in C.

CAUTION: You should take care of [Sequence Points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) while doing such things.

Answer (score 1):

Expression `(*s++ = *t++)` reads

1. read the character pointed at by `t`
2. store that character at the place pointed by `s`
3. advance `t` pointer by 1 position
4. advance `s` pointer by 1 position
5. return the value (the character) copied

and the `while();` instruction is

- while the value was not zero (i.e. we haven't copied the zero character string terminator yet) do nothing

where 'do nothing' is en empty instruction represented by the alone semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 0):

From C99 standerds

```
  An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment
```

When value pointed by `t` is `NULL`. it will be assigned to memory location pointed by `s`. And the overall value of that expression becomes `NULL`. It will break the while loop.

Comment: Variable `t` probably never gets `NULL` value, and the code never tests it. Additionally, even if `t` is NULL it will **NOT** be assigned to `s`.

Comment: `Variable t probably never gets NULL value, and the code never tests it.`  Agree on this. This condition must be checked. `even if t is NULL it will NOT be assigned to s`. Disagree. It will be always assigned to s(assumed s and n are pointers).

Comment: Nope. Characters pointed are copied, pointers are not. They are just incremented 'in parallel', but never one is copied to the other.

Comment: Yes True, Then  never copied to the other. Because we are deferring the pointer using `*`. Update answer to be more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Others have already answered the question. Although `*s++ = *t++` is unfortunately a rather commonly encountered line in C, I just want to point out the following:

- Using ++ together with other operators in the same expression is dangerous practice. There's always the potential of ending up with code which relies on the order of evaluation, which is unspecified behavior. And there's also the chance of invoking undefined behavior in case you happen to intentionally or accidentally modify the same variable twice without sequence points in between.

  Also, as we can see from this example, combining ++ with other operators make the code needlessly hard to read and enforces both the programmer and the reader to be 100% certain of all operator precedence rules in C.

  Optimal code is written in such a manner that each expression only has one side-effect. Therefore, optimal code doesn't mix ++ with other operands in the same expression. (See rules 12.2 12.4 12.13 of MISRA-C:2004, for some examples of where ++ can cause bugs.)
- Using assignment inside control statement expressions is regarded as bad practice. It makes the code harder to read, and there's the potential of mixing up = with ==. Good compilers warn against using = inside control statements. (See MISRA-C:2004 13.1)

So what you should do is to rewrite such dangerous, unreadable code into something clearer and safer. For example:

```
*s = *t

while(*t != '\0')
{
  s++,
  t++;
  *s = *t;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't a do..while loop be better in your example?

Comment: @mch Yeah a do-while is just as good. Personally I have no problem with do-while, but for some reason there's a lot of people who find it hard to read. Therefore I made a while loop on purpose.